# reactjs - conditional in label tag

Tags: reactjs

I have a requirement where I need to put a superscript hashtag at the end of a label for a certain item in each loop of ReactJS. Is it possible for me to accomplish this within the JSX itself?

```
if(props.data.length > 0){
        return props.data.map((each,i) => 
            <Col xs={12} md={3} key={i}>
                <Form.Group>
                    <Form.Check 
                        type="checkbox" 
                        label={each.service_name} <--- This particular label
                        id={`service_${i}`} 
                        {...props.register(`selectedService.${i}.value`) }
                        value={each.id}
                    />
                    {/* <CBDetail isChecked={} /> */}
                </Form.Group>
            </Col>
        )
    }
```

My unfinished workaround:

```
{each.service_name == ['Booklet', 'Logo', 'Newspaper'] ? ['Booklet<sup>#</sup>', ...]: each.service_name}
```

The output based on the condition would have a superscript hashtag if found on the condition loop.

```
Booklet#, Logo#, Newspaper#, .... (and the rest of the services)
```

I tried the ternary operator but it will only display the condition that I defined on the operator. I need it to apply to the condition that I defined but also display the rest of the data that is not defined to have the superscript hashtag at the end of the label.

I appreciate your guidance on this matter.